# How do I create an overload annotation for a function that returns a different type when the argument is 0 vs any other integer?

Tags: python, annotations, type-hinting, mypy

Is it possible to create an overload annotation for a function that returns a different type when argument is `0` vs any other integer?

```py
def foo(val: int) -> MyObjectA | MyObjectB:
    if val == 0:
        return MyObjectA()
    return MyObjectB()
```

Is there a way to overload that function to avoid the following?

`Incompatible types in assignment (expression has type "MyObjectA | MyObjectB", variable has type "MyObjectA") [assignment]`

```py
baz: MyObjectA = foo(0)
bar: MyObjectB = foo(1)
```

The problem I'm running into is that I can create the case for `Literal[0]` but I don't know how (or if it is even possible) to create the case for all other integers besides `0`.

```py
@overload
def foo(val: Literal[0]) -> MyObjectA:
    ...

# Is there some way to express all positive integers? or everything BUT 0?
@overload
def foo(val: Literal[1,2,3,4,5,6, ...]) -> MyObjectB: 
    ...
```

I thought maaaaybe there would be some way to express "not 0", but I didn't find anything like that in `typing`.

---

edit:

I tried the following hoping the order would give precedence to the `Literal[0]` but that unfortunately does not work.

```py
@overload
def foo(val: Literal[0]) -> MyObjectA:
    ...

@overload
def foo(val: int) -> MyObjectB:
    ...
```

Mypy will return this:

`Overloaded function signatures 1 and 2 overlap with incompatible return types [misc]`

Comment: Can you use `val: int` for the second overload, and the more specific literal will take precedence?

Comment: Unfortunately it doesn't look like it.  I was really hoping something like that would work.  I'll add the example to the post.

Comment: @Barmar "and the more specific literal will take precedence?" In my experience overlapping overloads are resolved from top to bottom.

Comment: Frame challenge: why does your function return incompatible objects depending on magic numbers to begin with? Isn’t there a Protocol/Interface that could cover both? Is `val` actually an arbitrary integer or rather something like an enum?

Comment: @MisterMiyagi in the real code its number of seconds. When above zero it returns seleniums `WebDriverWait`, when zero it returns a different object.  Challenge noted;  it does cause me to wonder if such a function needs to exist in it's current form.

Answer (score 1):

This *works*™️ depending on your upper limit.
It assumes there *is* a limit.  Since you're using seconds till timeout in your real-world code, it's a safe bet you have a limit.

```py
from typing import  Literal, TypeAlias

T_NotZero: TypeAlias = Literal[
    1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 
    24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31, 32, 33, 34, 35, 36, 37, 38, 39, 40, 41, 42, 43, 44,
    45, 46, 47, 48, 49, 50, 51, 52, 53, 54, 55, 56, 57, 58, 59, 60, 61, 62, 63, 64, 65, 
    66, 67, 68, 69, 70, 71, 72, 73, 74, 75, 76, 77, 78, 79, 80, 81, 82, 83, 84, 85, 86, 
    87, 88, 89, 90, 91, 92, 93, 94, 95, 96, 97, 98, 99, 100, 101, 102, 103, 104, 105, 
    106, 107, 108, 109, 110, 111, 112, 113, 114, 115, 116, 117, 118, 119, 120, 121, 122, 
    123, 124, 125, 126, 127, 128, 129, 130, 131, 132, 133, 134, 135, 136, 137, 138, 139, 
    140, 141, 142, 143, 144, 145, 146, 147, 148, 149, 150, 151, 152, 153, 154, 155, 156, 
    157, 158, 159, 160, 161, 162, 163, 164, 165, 166, 167, 168, 169, 170, 171, 172, 173, 
    174, 175, 176, 177, 178, 179, 180, 181, 182, 183, 184, 185, 186, 187, 188, 189, 190, 
    191, 192, 193, 194, 195, 196, 197, 198, 199, 200, 201, 202, 203, 204, 205, 206, 207,
    208, 209, 210, 211, 212, 213, 214, 215, 216, 217, 218, 219, 220, 221, 222, 223, 224,
    225, 226, 227, 228, 229, 230, 231, 232, 233, 234, 235, 236, 237, 238, 239, 240, 241,
    242, 243, 244, 245, 246, 247, 248, 249, 250, 251, 252, 253, 254, 255, 256, 257, 258,
    259, 260, 261, 262, 263, 264, 265, 266, 267, 268, 269, 270, 271, 272, 273, 274, 275,
    276, 277, 278, 279, 280, 281, 282, 283, 284, 285, 286, 287, 288, 289, 290, 291, 292,
    293, 294, 295, 296, 297, 298, 299, 300, 301, 302, 303, 304, 305, 306, 307, 308, 309,
    310, 311, 312, 313, 314, 315, 316, 317, 318, 319, 320, 321, 322, 323, 324, 325, 326,
    327, 328, 329, 330, 331, 332, 333, 334, 335, 336, 337, 338, 339, 340, 341, 342, 343,
    344, 345, 346, 347, 348, 349, 350, 351, 352, 353, 354, 355, 356, 357, 358, 359, 360,
    361, 362, 363, 364, 365, 366, 367, 368, 369, 370, 371, 372, 373, 374, 375, 376, 377, 
    378, 379, 380, 381, 382, 383, 384, 385, 386, 387, 388, 389, 390, 391, 392, 393, 394, 
    395, 396, 397, 398, 399, 400, 401, 402, 403, 404, 405, 406, 407, 408, 409, 410, 411,
    412, 413, 414, 415, 416, 417, 418, 419, 420, 421, 422, 423, 424, 425, 426, 427, 428,
    429, 430, 431, 432, 433, 434, 435, 436, 437, 438, 439, 440, 441, 442, 443, 444, 445, 
    446, 447, 448, 449, 450, 451, 452, 453, 454, 455, 456, 457, 458, 459, 460, 461, 462, 
    463, 464, 465, 466, 467, 468, 469, 470, 471, 472, 473, 474, 475, 476, 477, 478, 479, 
    480, 481, 482, 483, 484, 485, 486, 487, 488, 489, 490, 491, 492, 493, 494, 495, 496, 
    497, 498, 499, 500, 501, 502, 503, 504, 505, 506, 507, 508, 509, 510, 511, 512, 513,
    514, 515, 516, 517, 518, 519, 520, 521, 522, 523, 524, 525, 526, 527, 528, 529, 530, 
    531, 532, 533, 534, 535, 536, 537, 538, 539, 540, 541, 542, 543, 544, 545, 546, 547, 
    548, 549, 550, 551, 552, 553, 554, 555, 556, 557, 558, 559, 560, 561, 562, 563, 564,
    565, 566, 567, 568, 569, 570, 571, 572, 573, 574, 575, 576, 577, 578, 579, 580, 581, 
    582, 583, 584, 585, 586, 587, 588, 589, 590, 591, 592, 593, 594, 595, 596, 597, 598, 
    599, 600, 601, 602, 603, 604, 605, 606, 607, 608, 609, 610, 611, 612, 613, 614, 615, 
    616, 617, 618, 619, 620, 621, 622, 623, 624, 625, 626, 627, 628, 629, 630, 631, 632,
    633, 634, 635, 636, 637, 638, 639, 640, 641, 642, 643, 644, 645, 646, 647, 648, 649, 
    650, 651, 652, 653, 654, 655, 656, 657, 658, 659, 660, 661, 662, 663, 664, 665, 666, 
    667, 668, 669, 670, 671, 672, 673, 674, 675, 676, 677, 678, 679, 680, 681, 682, 683, 
    684, 685, 686, 687, 688, 689, 690, 691, 692, 693, 694, 695, 696, 697, 698, 699, 700, 
    701, 702, 703, 704, 705, 706, 707, 708, 709, 710, 711, 712, 713, 714, 715, 716, 717, 
    718, 719, 720, 721, 722, 723, 724, 725, 726, 727, 728, 729, 730, 731, 732, 733, 734, 
    735, 736, 737, 738, 739, 740, 741, 742, 743, 744, 745, 746, 747, 748, 749, 750, 751, 
    752, 753, 754, 755, 756, 757, 758, 759, 760, 761, 762, 763, 764, 765, 766, 767, 768, 
    769, 770, 771, 772, 773, 774, 775, 776, 777, 778, 779, 780, 781, 782, 783, 784, 785, 
    786, 787, 788, 789, 790, 791, 792, 793, 794, 795, 796, 797, 798, 799, 800, 801, 802,
    803, 804, 805, 806, 807, 808, 809, 810, 811, 812, 813, 814, 815, 816, 817, 818, 819,
    820, 821, 822, 823, 824, 825, 826, 827, 828, 829, 830, 831, 832, 833, 834, 835, 836, 
    837, 838, 839, 840, 841, 842, 843, 844, 845, 846, 847, 848, 849, 850, 851, 852, 853, 
    854, 855, 856, 857, 858, 859, 860, 861, 862, 863, 864, 865, 866, 867, 868, 869, 870, 
    871, 872, 873, 874, 875, 876, 877, 878, 879, 880, 881, 882, 883, 884, 885, 886, 887,
    888, 889, 890, 891, 892, 893, 894, 895, 896, 897, 898, 899, 900, 901, 902, 903, 904, 
    905, 906, 907, 908, 909, 910, 911, 912, 913, 914, 915, 916, 917, 918, 919, 920, 921,
    922, 923, 924, 925, 926, 927, 928, 929, 930, 931, 932, 933, 934, 935, 936, 937, 938, 
    939, 940, 941, 942, 943, 944, 945, 946, 947, 948, 949, 950, 951, 952, 953, 954, 955, 
    956, 957, 958, 959, 960, 961, 962, 963, 964, 965, 966, 967, 968, 969, 970, 971, 972, 
    973, 974, 975, 976, 977, 978, 979, 980, 981, 982, 983, 984, 985, 986, 987, 988, 989, 
    990, 991, 992, 993, 994, 995, 996, 997, 998, 999]
```

Comment: Out of curiosity, what would you do if you were the reviewer?

Comment: After snorting my coffee through my nose, I would ask them to explain or perhaps justify this.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your Python version you could do either one:

```
from __future__ import annotations
def foo(val: int) -> MyObjectA | MyObjectB:
  if not type(val) is int:
    raise TypeError(f"The parameter {val} is not an integer!")
  if val == 0:
    return MyObjectA()
  return MyObjectB()


from typing import Union
def bar(val: int) -> Union[MyObjectA, MyObjectB]:
  if not type(val) is int:
    raise TypeError(f"The parameter {val} is not an integer!")
  if val == 0:
    return MyObjectA()
  return MyObjectB()


class MyObjectA:
  pass

class MyObjectB:
  pass


print("running foo")

print(foo(0))
print(foo(1))
print(foo(100))

print("running bar")
print(bar(0))
print(bar(1))
print(bar(100))

print("Throw error if not int")
print(foo(2.9))
```

Also, using typing/annotations does not enforce a specific type, so it would probably be better to check for a type if you really want to make sure...

Comment: This is not an answer. The question is abaout type hinting, not runtime typechecking.

Answer (score 0):

In both mypy and pyright you can just use `int` and silence the error; "Overloaded function signatures 1 and 2 overlap with incompatible return types [misc]".

In typeshed [Python's `open`](https://github.com/python/typeshed/blob/6eec191739f7f39752ae1e95a7d7cf18fca4c12b/stdlib/builtins.pyi#L1626) does something similar.

```py
from typing import Any, Literal, overload

class MyObjectA: ...
class MyObjectB: ...


@overload
def foo(val: Literal[0]) -> MyObjectA: ...  # type: ignore

@overload
def foo(val: int) -> MyObjectB: ...


def foo(val: Any) -> Any:
    pass


reveal_type(foo(0))
reveal_type(foo(1))
```

```
test.py:18: note: Revealed type is "test.MyObjectA"
test.py:19: note: Revealed type is "test.MyObjectB"
Success: no issues found in 1 source file
```

**Note**: You can really easily change the type of `Literal[0]` to `int`. For example `reveal_type(foo([0][0]))` is `MyObjectB` as `[0]` becomes `list[int]` not `list[Literal[0]]`.

Comment: The problem with this solution is that it only works correctly if you have perfect knowledge about the value of the parameter. If the type checker doesn't understand that the input value is 0, the runtime type will differ from the statically inferred type. For example, mypy thinks that `foo([0, 1, 2][0])` returns a `MyObjectB`, but in reality it returns a `MyObjectA`.

Comment: @Aran-Fey Since `[0, 1, 2]`'s type is `list[int]`, as you've noted, the solution here will resolve to `MyObjectB`. The best alternate solution using `Literal[every number under the sun - 0]` instead will error with any value which resolves to a type `int`. Which I guess is important to note.

Comment: I guess I should've been more specific. What I was trying to get at is that silencing the error isn't a good idea - instead, an input of type `int` should result in an output of type `MyObjectA | MyObjectB`.

Comment: @Aran-Fey I would have to really see the code in action to confidently say what the best return type is. For my example `MyObjectA` and `MyObjectB` you _could_ be correct. However if `int` is provided a lot then the benefit to the overload is pretty much pointless, and I'd just remove the `overload` all together. I can't really comment on hypotheticals.