# What is type annotation for "any callable but a class" in Python using Mypy?

Tags: python, python-3.x, type-hinting, mypy

I'm trying to perfectly type annotate the following Python function:

```py
from typing import Callable, Any
import inspect

def foo(func: Callable[..., Any]) -> None:
    if inspect.isclass(func):
        raise ValueError
    # Do something...

class Bad:
    pass

def good() -> Bad:
    return Bad()


foo(good)  # OK
foo(Bad)   # NOK
```

I would like to narrow down the `Callable[..., Any]` type so that it rejects `Bad` passed as argument.

See Mypy playground [here](https://mypy-play.net/?mypy=latest&python=3.10&flags=show-error-codes%2Cstrict&gist=ded1db9e24ac4ef3aaec2a01b9f55463).

I can't find anything in the [`typing`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html) module nor the [Mypy](https://mypy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/) documentation to distinguish between a simple function and a class. Is this even possible?

It's not clear why `type(Bad)` and `type(good)` are very distinct at run-time, but I can't find the equivalent for type annotation.

Comment: Function and Bound method are distinct types. You can make a union of those, but it would exclude anything else with a `__call__` method.

Comment: Maybe this is XY? *Why* do you want to exclude classes? They are just as callable as anything else, since `type` defines `__call__`...

Comment: @MadPhysicist Can you please point me to the `Function` distinct type? I don't see it referenced in the `typing` module.

Comment: @MadPhysicist My function is a wrapper around a function, and it was often misused to wrap an entire `class`, causing unexpected behavior to users. I needed to disallow it.

Comment: There's no way to say "type X except for subtype Y" in Python type hints. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57854871/exclude-type-in-python-typing-annotation#:~:text=Python%20type%20hinting%20can't,actually%20using%20in%20the%20dictionary.

Comment: @Barmar I understand, that's why I'm looking for a type less generic than "Callable".

Comment: As pointed out in that question, you have to list all the types you want to allow. There's no existing type that's what you want.

Comment: @Barmar Is there a `Function` type as mentioned by @MadPhysicist?

Comment: I can't find a reference to Function or Bound, but maybe I'm looking in the wrong places. I looked in the `typing` module.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As you may know, `Callable` is a kind of [structural type](https://peps.python.org/pep-0544/), and so anything with the `__call__` instance method (which includes all classes, because a class is an instance of `type`, and [`type.__call__`](https://github.com/python/typeshed/blob/96eaa767ddfb5b206e0a57a5663daf07212b2675/stdlib/builtins.pyi#L195) allows you to use the call syntax `Bad()`) will fulfil `Callable`.

Statically typing something to behave differently for a subset of a type is not fully supported in the Python typing system; you'll face the same problems if you try, for example, to type something as ["an integer but not `0`"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77070267/how-do-i-create-an-overload-annotation-for-a-function-that-returns-a-different-t). The closest you can get is making a [`@typing.overload`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.overload) with [`typing.Never`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.Never), which says that `foo` will error at runtime, which is your implementation of `foo` anyway. Here, mypy will throw an error on the first line after the call site expected to fail at runtime (example given at [mypy-playground](https://mypy-play.net/?mypy=latest&python=3.10&flags=show-error-codes%2Cstrict%2Cwarn-unreachable&gist=3e9beddc6907af14c13522c0c0e094d3), copied below):

```py
from typing_extensions import Callable, Any, overload, Never
import inspect

@overload
def foo(func: type) -> Never: ...

@overload
def foo(func: Callable[..., Any]) -> None: ...

def foo(func: Callable[..., Any]) -> None:
    if inspect.isclass(func):
        raise ValueError
    # Do something...

class Bad:
    pass

def good() -> Bad:
    return Bad()


foo(good)  # OK
foo(Bad)   # NOK
a = 3  # mypy: Statement is unreachable [unreachable]
```

This requires specifying the `--warn-unreachable` CLI option or `warn_unreachable = True` configuration file option to work.

Answer (score 0):

From the comments, it sounds like what you're really looking for is an annotation for the standard user-defined function type. That's [`types.FunctionType`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/types.html#types.FunctionType):

```
import types

def foo(func: types.FunctionType) -> None:
    ...
```

Note, that says `types`. Not `typing`. `typing` is a different module.

Comment: Unfortunately, at the time of writing, type-checkers (at least mypy) don't recognise plain `def` functions as `types.FunctionType`. See [mypy-playground](https://mypy-play.net/?mypy=latest&python=3.10&flags=show-error-codes%2Cstrict%2Cwarn-unreachable&gist=47247a43f4ad0680478cfbb207bec746).

Comment: @dROOOze: Huh. Well, that sucks.