Python stub: how to annotate properly a function that uses CPython PySequence_Check?
I have a function implemented in C that is exposed to python (c extension) that accepts a sequence. Its signature looks something like this:
from typing import Sequence


def my_c_func(my_sequence: Sequence[TypeDoesntMatter]):
    ...

But the thing is, Sequence generic is way more descriptive than what PySequence_Check validates as a sequence (source), as documentation for PySequence_Check clearly states that it returns 1 if an object has __getitem__ magic method, unless it's a dict. Satisfying the first part is easy: creating a custom generic with __getitem__, but marking that the value cannot be a dictionary or its subclass? - at least according to this answer is impossible.
Why I think that this question is not a duplicate of the already mentioned one? First of, the solution given there doesn't work for my use-case, and secondly, while excluding a dictionary is one of the solutions that could work (if it was possible), It isn't the only theoretical solution that could exist for my issue.

It looks like you're wanting to hint the old-style iteration protocol. For the purposes of type annotations, I think it's perfectly okay for the public API to be stricter  / more descriptive than the implementation; do you really want to accept anything with __getitem__ that doesn't a dict?

Well, that's a good explanation - yes, it isn't much an issue if type annotations are stricter than what my function supports and probably type checkers should be smart enough to detect that dict shouldn't be given to that function. Still, I hoped that there was a more direct way to annotate my function, but this isn't a blocker in any way. Thanks for taking time to investigate this topic.

In any case, this is a similar question: https://stackoverflow.com/q/77160524/ and the answer is "use @typing.overload with typing.Never". They're asking for "any callable except a class", you're asking for "any structural type with __getitem__ except a dict".
